# Insert Line Breaks on User Input

Tags: html, input

I allow users to put content on my website using HTML `TextArea`, but whenever they upload content, it doesn't contain linebreaks, even if they were to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> twice. How can I put linebreaks in?

Answer (score 1):

What text editor are you using?

If you aren't using one, then you'll need to have JavaScript insert `<p></p>`  or `<br /><br />` after every time they hit 'enter'.

Of course, if users are putting content on your site, then you also need to watch any HTML they can put up, and make it so that they can't upload 'bad' HTML.

Jeff Atwood [wrote one such utility for C#](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html). You'll have to check and see if whatever language you're using on the back end supports it.

Comment: hii and thanks for your help
i not using any editor .
and when users put there content it also puts <br/> after every line break

but when they want to see the content but not in the editor 
so it shows with no line breaks

i dont know why it happens .

i dont know why but it ignores the <br/> or any html tag

what can i do??

Comment: What site are you referring to?  Can you post the code that does the POST of the TextArea code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the contents of the textarea in html you could replace linebreak characters with `<br/>`.

Comment: i did that 
 dont know why but it ignores the <br/> or any html tag what can i do??